# Where is terraform binary in Ubuntu after update?

Tags: terraform

I had terraform v0.14.5 installed on my Ubuntu Jenkins build node.

```
$ which terraform
/usr/local/bin/terraform
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.14.5

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.2.7. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

So I followed [APT Packages for Debian and Ubuntu](https://www.terraform.io/cli/install/apt) to install the latest version, which is currently v1.2.7, and it installed successfully.

```
$ apt policy terraform
terraform:
  Installed: 1.2.7
  Candidate: 1.2.7
```

However, I still get

```
$ which terraform
/usr/local/bin/terraform
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.14.5

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.2.7. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

How do I set the executable to the latest installed terraform version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dpkg -L terraform`, this will list all installed files from this package.

`which` looks for binaries in the `PATH` environment variable. If `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin`, then `/usr/local/bin/terraform` will always show up first.

E.g. my PATH variable has this order

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/olaf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Thanks you! I forgot about the `dpkg` command. I adjusted my `PATH` variable and all is well.